# Find files in a folder, compress them to a target location without directory structure in Linux terminal

Tags: linux, command-line, tar

In Linux terminal:
I'm in a folder say `/home/user/origlocation/` I need to goto a folder let's say `../source/` and find all files with the name `test*.txt`. Then I need to compress (tar.gz) these files to a location say `/home/user/target/` and most importantly without the directory structure in the tar file (i need only the filenames in the immediate extracted tar results). Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should work

```
cd ../source && tar -cvf foo.tar test*.txt;
mv ./foo.tar /home/user/target/ && cd ../origlocation
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanted a different approach, but this works pretty fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a newish `tar`, you could do this:

```
find ../source -name 'test*.txt' | tar --transform='s,.*/,,' -cvzf /home/user/target/test-txt.tar.gz -T-
```

This works by using `find` to generate a list of files in the target directory and below. `tar` then reads this list from the pipe as `stdin` (using "-T-"), then creates the desired archive (including compression with `gzip`), transforming the output file paths using the `sed` expression, which strips off all the leading directory components.

If in fact all your files are in a single directory, it's simpler still:

```
(cd ../source; tar -cvzf /home/user/target/test-txt.tar.gz test*.txt)
```

This works by using a sub-shell to move you to the target directory, but still writes the tar archive to the required final location. No directory components are included because you're using a straightforward shell glob to select the files in the working directory).